# Python check Palindrome

Tags: python-3.x, palindrome

I was solving the problem at Codesignal
and saw one of the solutions that check palindrome like this.

```
def checkPalindrome(inputString):
    return inputString == inputString[::-1]
```

How is that working?
Please explain what is going on here.

Comment: inputString[::-1] is the easiest way to reverse the string.

you are checking whether the given input is equal to its reverse order.

Comment: Here's the opposite question: [Reverse a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/931092/4518341)

Comment: It just creates a reversed copy of inputString

Answer (score 1):

`inputString[::-1]` returns the reverse of `inputString`. A palindrome is the same word spelled backwards and forwards, and that's what the equality operator checks.